# mfc dialog button rect

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have a window with a button, and I want to anchor the button in one corner at window re-size, but somehow when I try to retrieve the button's `rect`, a `debug assertion error` is thrown.

```
void CDaf_Alarm_ComplexDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
 {
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    CRect winRect;
    GetWindowRect(&winRect);

    CRect buttonRect;
    m_btnAnulare.GetWindowRect(&buttonRect);

    m_btnAnulare.SetWindowPos(NULL,winRect.right - buttonRect.Width(), buttonRect.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
}
```

The error is thrown at the line `m_btnAnulare.GetWindowRect(&buttonRect);` because it returns negative values (probably `NULL`).

`m_btnAnulare` is a CButton item declared in `.h`.

Comment: `GetWindowRect()` has a `void` return type. What makes you think it is returning `NULL`?

Comment: i expressed myself wrong. what i wanted to say is that the values that are passed to `buttonRect` are negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `CButton` has not been created / subclassed yet. Did you check the m_hWnd member? Is it still `nullptr`.
Check with `GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr` before accessing it.

Comment: Indeed, the `CButton` hadn't been created yet. But now, after reposition, the button dissapears...do i have to call a repaint method after repositioning or something like that?

Comment: I am not excactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but did you check the value for your call to `SetWindowPos`:
`winRect.right - buttonRect.Width(), buttonRect.top` Do these width and height values make sense?

Comment: The window position is relative to its parent window. To make it simple, I'd just call GetClientRect() on the dialog.  You can call GetWindowRect() on the dialog, but then you are going to have to translate coordinates by calling ScreenToClient().